# Необходимо удалить из текстового файла слова, длинна которых превышает заданное количество символов. PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день!

**Задача:** *Есть текстовый файл
Необходимо удалить из него все слова, длина которых превышает N символов.
Значение N задавать через форму.
Проверить работу на кириллических строках - найти ошибку, найти решение.*

Задачу решил разбить на более мелкие подзадачи:

1. Запись содержимого файла в строку;
2. Удаление знаков препинания(удалить все кроме букв, цифр и пробелов), двойного пробела;
3. Разбитие строки на слова и запись в массив;
4. Перебор массива слов:

   4.1  Отсеивание слов длинна которых больше значения N;

   4.2  Удаление из текста слов длинна которых больше значения N.

Дальше пока не продвинулся застрял на ***4.2*** Судя по всему не получается удалить подстроку из строки при помощи функции  str_replace.

**Выдает ошибку:**

```
E_COMPILE_ERROR : type 64 -- Cannot redeclare deleteWordsInFile() (previously declared in /home/ifiddlen/application/controllers/main.php(256) : eval()'d code:22) -- at line 58
```

Так же косовато исполнено:

*2. Удаление знаков препинания(удалить все кроме букв, цифр и пробелов), двойного пробела, но это вопрос уже второстепенный.*

P.S. Я новичок, поэтому сам способ решения это задачи кривоват есть ли более «ровное» решение этой задачи, кто что посоветует, что нужно сделать и какие функции применить.

**Код файла 03.php:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Задание 3</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>3. Есть текстовый файл.
    Необходимо удалить из него все слова, длина которых превыщает N символов.
    Значение N задавать через форму.
    Проверить работу на кириллических строках - найти ошибку, найти решение.
    </h3>
    <form action="03.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <lable for="first">Введите количество: </br></lable>
        </p>
        <input type = "text" id="first" name="num">
        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />     
    </form>
<?php
    //Функция удаления слов из файла.
    function deleteWordsInFile ($num) {
        //1.Запись содержимого файла в строку
        $text = file_get_contents('text.txt');
        //Провераем что содержимое фала записано в строку.
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($text);
        echo "</pre>";
        //2.Удаление знаков препинания(удалить все кроме букв, цифр и пробелов), двойного пробела.
        //Удобный сервис надо не забыть "http://regexr.ru/".
        $content = preg_replace('/([^a-zа-я\s]|\s{2})/ui', "",$text);

        //echo "<pre>";
        //var_dump($content);
        //echo "</pre>";

        //Проверяем передалось ли значение через форму.
        echo "$num</br>";

        //3. Разбитие строки на слова и запись в массив.
        $words = explode(" ", $content);

        $cutText = $text;
        //4. Перебор массива слов
        foreach ($words as $item){
    //5. Отсеивание слов длинна которых больше значения N.
            if (mb_strlen($item) > 10){
                var_dump($item);
                echo mb_strlen($item);
                echo "</br>";
                //6. Удаление из текста слов длинна которых больше значения N.
               $cutText = str_replace("$item", "", $text);
            };
        };

        var_dump($cutText);

     };

    if(array_key_exists('num', $_POST) && strlen($_POST['num']) > 0) {
            deleteWordsInFile($_POST['num']);
    };
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Текстовый файл text.txt:**

Славное кафе на площади Сен-Мишель
А потом погода испортилась. Она переменилась в один день – и осень кончилась. Из-за дождя нам приходилось закрывать на ночь окна, холодный ветер срывал листья с деревьев на площади Контрэскарп. Листья лежали размоченные дождем, и ветер швырял дождь в большой зеленый автобус на конечной остановке, а кафе «Для любителей» было переполнено, и окна запотели изнутри от тепла и табачного дыма. Это было мрачное кафе с дурной репутацией, где собирались пьяницы со всего квартала, и я не ходил туда, потому что там пахло потом и кислым винным перегаром. Мужчины и женщины, завсегдатаи кафе «Для любителей», были всегда пьяны, вернее, пили до тех пор, пока у них были деньги, а пили они чаще всего вино, которое покупали по поллитра или по литру. Там рекламировалось множество аперитивов со странными названиями, но мало кто мог себе их позволить, разве что для начала, чтобы поскорее напиться. Женщин-пьяниц называли poivrottes, что означает «алкоголички».

Comment: Ваша ошибка говорит о том, что Вы пытаетесь определить функцию `deleteWordsInFile` второй раз

Comment: Я так и не понял где ее(функция deleteWordsInFile) определил первый раз, если изменить название функции ошибка остается.

Comment: Возможно Вы просто делаете `include` этого скрипта пару раз, отсюда и ошибка (скорее всего из-за этого). Подумайте где это возможно и попробуйте заменить на `include_once`, что скажет в этом случае

Comment: Ошибка E_COMPILE_ERROR : type 64 -- Cannot redeclare deleteWordsInFile() (previously declared in /home/ifiddlen/application/controllers/main.php(256) : eval()'d code:22) -- at line 58 ушла.

Comment: Остались вопросы: не получается удалить подстроку из строки при помощи функции str_replace.
Есть ли более «ровное» решение этой задачи, кто что посоветует, что нужно сделать и какие функции применить.

Comment: А что не так с удалением подстроки? У меня всё нормально работает.
И немного по мелочи: `mb_strlen($item) > 10` - здесь вместо 10  должен быть `$num`, Вы видимо пропустили и в `str_replace("$item"`, кавычки можно от `$item` убрать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы задачу решил другим способом.